# How to add git hook for sending commit messages into pivotal tracker story as comments?

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite, pivotaltracker

I am using mac os, git(without github), gitolite as git server and pivotal tracker.

I would like to add git hook which notify pushed commit for ex: `[#432324] some commit` will add as a comment to PT story. And maybe I will be able to close finish story when in commit message will be 'Fixed' text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create and post a JSON request to the PT API from  a **post-update** or a **post-receive** hook. It’s not too complicated - [here’s an example you can base your work on](https://github.com/bentasker/notify-webhook-pivotal-tracker/blob/master/notify-webhook-pivotal-tracker.py).

<sub>Contrary to the general etiquette I’m not pasting the relevant parts of the quoted link, because there is nothing unique here in the way REST APIs can be accessed, and the data supplied will be specific to the submitter.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The [`git_tracker`](https://github.com/stevenharman/git_tracker) does exactly what you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22806028/197944).